# Can contract run a custom function outside of its cordapp?

Tags: corda

There's a `Utility` cordapp that contains all the helper constants/methods.
The `Contract` cordapp has a dependency on `Utilities` and some of its contract code is running the constants or methods in `Utility` cordapp.

Is this a safe practice? If someone were to change the implementation of the helper method in `Utility`, it would fail on the responder side since they have the original `Utility` cordapp implmentation?

Answer (score 0):

In the Corda endstate:

- Contract JARs will be fat JARs that contain not only `Contract` subclasses, but also any dependencies of these `Contract` subclasses (i.e. any classes referenced from these contracts)
- The deterministic JVM will be sandboxed to only load classes from these contract JARs

Because contract JARs are pinned down by hash in transactions, you know that both parties are using the exact same version of any classes.

As of Corda 3, this functionality isn't implemented. Once it is, the design pattern you discuss above will be safe.